# Looping through seq with negative numbers in R

Tags: r, loops, sequence

This is probably very simple, but I am having trouble getting R to loop through negative numbers. I have tried using seq(-10,10,1), I have tried using seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)
What I get is either b values of 1-10 or 1-21. I need it to be from -10 to 10. What am I missing in here? Any help is very appreciated.

Here is my current attempt at the code:

````
pr1 <- NULL
i <- 1
t = seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 1)

for (b in seq(t)) {
  LLF <- sum(1*log((1/(1+exp(-(b)))))+(1-1)*log(1-(1/(1+exp(-(b))))))
  like[b] <- LLF
  pr[b] <- b 
}
pr
df <-data.frame(like, pr)```
````

Comment: It does produce the expected results, so it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

Several errors. Failing to distinguish values from their integer order and failing to initialize variables used in a for-loop:

```
pr1 <- NULL
i <- 1
(t = seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 1) )
like <- numeric(); pr <- numeric() # need to exist to do subscripted assignment
for (b in seq_along(t) ) {
    # Note the use of b used to index the `t` vector
    LLF <- sum(1*log((1/(1+exp(-( t[b] )))))+(1-1)*log(1-(1/(1+exp(-( t[b] ))))))
    like[b] <- LLF
    pr[b] <- b 
}
pr
df <-data.frame(like, pr)
```

Probably NOT a good idea to use `t` as a variable name. It's an R function name that transposed matrices. Same goes for `df` which is the density function for the F distribution. Thos are not errors but cautions to prevent strange error messages and confusion amont humans. R can keep object names distinct from function names.

Answer (score -1):

You just need `for (b in t) {` because t already represents the sequence you want.

Comment: It is still only taking the positive values with this change.

Comment: `t = seq(from = -10, to = 10, by = 1); for (b in t) { print(b) }` definitely prints out negative numbers.

Comment: @BrianMontgomery You should run your suggested edits before submitting. The failure to initialize would have also been apparent. The problem with using `t` as the sequence is that b is also being used as an index and the result of indexing with a negative number is that you get no result.